# Authenticating my web site with MSA in Debug mode

Tags: oauth-2.0, social-authentication

**Issue:** On Launching the Web application in debug mode, Authentication is getting failed.

**Detailed steps that i have implemented in debug mode:**
1.Registered my application in Microsoft developer center
2.Modified my project URL to the same domain name, that i have used to register.
3.Used the Client ID and Secret key, from the registered application in web application.
4.Launched the sample application with the registered URL, in visual studio.
5.On clicking on Microsoft button, to authenticate- i am getting landed in error page.
6.Error URL: https://login.live.com/err.srf?lc=1033#error=invalid_request&error_description=The+provided+value+for+the+input+parameter+'redirect_uri'+is+not+valid.

+The+expected+value+is+'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf'+or+a+URL+which+matches+the+redirect+URI+registered+for+this+client+application.

**Queries:**
*1.Is it possible to verify the MSA Authentication in local environment in debug mode? 
2.Does Microsoft authentication page re-directs to my localhost (at any case).*

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer (click the white checkmark) if the answer meets your needs. It lets others know the question has been answered correctly, it awards you 2 points for accepting an answer, and it awards 15 points to the person that provided the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in your step 2. *"2.Modified my project URL to the same domain name, that i have used to register."*

To whatever URL you are using to register your app you have to append `/signin-microsoft`, i.e., if the URL for your app is, for example `https://localhost:44300`, then when you register your app with Microsoft the Redirect URI has to be `https://localhost:44300/signin-microsoft`. Therefore:

*1.Is it possible to verify the MSA Authentication in local environment in debug mode?*

**Yes, follow my steps above (it has nothing to do with debug mode)**

*2.Does Microsoft authentication page re-directs to my localhost (at any case)*

**Yes, if you append `/signin-microsoft` to your app URL when registering it**